# C++ - Check cin for mistakes

Tags: c++, cin

I have a while loop that restarts if the users inputs something wrong.

```
do{
    cerr<<"Input the numbers divided by a space"<<endl;
    cin>>number1>>number2;
    hiba=(cin.fail() || number1<1 || number1>100 || number2<1 || number2>100);
    if(fail){
        getline(cin, sz);
        cerr<<"Wrong input"<<endl;
    }
}while(fail);
```

Both variables are integers and it works if the numbers are either below 0 or above 100, but it doesn't work if the user inputs a character, because it starts an infinite loop.

Comment: Please translate to English, and write what do you mean by "it works".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
int main()
{
    int tanulokszama,versenyekszama;
    bool hiba;
    string sz;
    do{
        cerr<<"Adja meg az elsõ sort!"<<endl;
        cin>>tanulokszama>>versenyekszama;
        hiba=(cin.fail() || tanulokszama<1 || tanulokszama>100 || versenyekszama<1 || versenyekszama>100);
        if(hiba){
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
            //getline(cin, sz);
            cerr<<"Rossz adatot adott meg!"<<endl;
        }
    }while(hiba);
}
```

Note:

Dont forget to include

```
 #include<limits>
```

Comment: Dont forget to mark as answer if it has solved the problem for you.

Comment: But now if both of the numbers are below 0 or above 100, then I have to press enter twice, after asking for the input again.

Comment: If I remove getline it works for wrong numbers but not for characters. It starts an infinite loop.

Comment: I changed the code, try the new one, it dosent go in infinite loop

Comment: It almost works. If both inputs are characters, then it prints out "Adja meg az elsõ sort!" and "Rossz adatot adott meg!" twice.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [ignore()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) and [clear()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) functions to clear the stream and ignore anything until '\n'.

Try this:

```
do{
    cerr<<"Adja meg az elsõ sort!"<<endl;
    cin>>tanulokszama>>versenyekszama;
    hiba=(cin.fail() || tanulokszama<1 || tanulokszama>100 || versenyekszama<1 || versenyekszama>100);
    if(hiba){
        cin.clear();//clear the error flags of the stream
        cerr<<"Rossz adatot adott meg!"<<endl;
        cin.ignore( 256, '\n');//ignore until '\n'
    }
}while(hiba);
```

Or even better include limits header file and use the following:

```
#include <limits>//add this to your includes
do{
    cerr<<"Adja meg az elsõ sort!"<<endl;
    cin>>tanulokszama>>versenyekszama;
    hiba=(cin.fail() || tanulokszama<1 || tanulokszama>100 || versenyekszama<1 || versenyekszama>100);
    if(hiba){
        cin.clear();//clear the error flags of the stream
        cerr<<"Rossz adatot adott meg!"<<endl;
        cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');//extract anything until the '\n' occurs
    }
}while(hiba);
```